# Issue with retrieving Double number from Firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, firebase, double

I am currently working on restaurants' project where from by pressing a button on Restaurant View controller I am viewing the location of the restaurant on google map (map view controller). In order to place latitude and longitude in my map code, I have an issue with retrieving Double numbers from Firebase. Whenever I try to print them, I get this error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)"

```
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyRQKeLyKH5CsrDPpPsjy7nYqudEbqXmQS2")
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("amsterdam")
        ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: self.appDelegate.selectedBarName).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children{
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let mapSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "map")
                if let snapDict = mapSnap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                    let dictValues = [AnyObject](snapDict.values)
                    for each in dictValues{
                        let latitude = each["map_latitude"] as! Double
                        let longitude = each["map_longitude"] as! Double

                        print(latitude)
                        print(longitude)
                       let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, zoom: 6.0)
                        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
                        self.view = mapView
                        let marker = GMSMarker()
                        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                        marker.map = mapView
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is to get the value from **each**.
Try this line to get the value if **each** as a dictionary object.

```
let latitude = each.object(forKey:"map_latitude") as! Double
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not really work( I got this error with this message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000427420'

Comment: Please check the value of **each** object and also the **dictValues**. If you please provide the values **dictValues** then I will try to provide the solution.

Comment: I've checked the values of each and dictValues. Everything displays correctly. Probably the issue is with getting the separate values of latitude and longitude